# Arithmetic problem with shell script

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, shell

I've got some issues on scripting... if someone could help me, it would be really good !

My script  has:

```
VISITS=$((WR + RD));
SERVICE_DEMAND=$((VISITS*SERVICE_DEMAND));
```

And I'm getting this error:

> ./calc_serv_demand.sh: line 12:
>   0.0895406: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is
>   ".0895406")

Can someone help me?

I think it's because the bash works only with integer... I need to use float values, though.

thanks in advance

---

Problem solved:

VISITS=$(echo $WR + $RD | bc);
echo $VISITS

SERVICE_DEMAND=$(echo $VISITS '*' $SERVICE_TIME | bc);
echo $SERVICE_DEMAND

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `bc` to do your floating point calculations, i.e.

```
echo $WR + $RD | bc
```

and so on.

Comment: HUm...

it works for the sum, it doesn't work well for the multiplication. 

It's weird because I've checked on bc manual and it should work !

Have a look:

My script:

echo $WR + $RD | bc &> VISITS;
VISITS=$(echo $WR + $RD | bc); # works fine
echo $VISITS

SERVICE_DEMAND=$(echo $VISITS * $SERVICE_TIME | bc); # return a weird error
echo $SERVICE_DEMAND

Error:

0.0895406
3.42007
12.401
3.5096106
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: K
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: H
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: T
...

Comment: @user: Since `*` has a special meaning for the shell you have to write either `\\*` or `'*'`.

Also, you should directly assign the result of the calculation to a variable instead of outputting to file: `VISITS=$(echo $WR + $RD | bc)`.

Comment: @user368453: If you do an `echo` of an `*` it displays all the filenames in the current directory. Just put quotes around the formula and it will work: `SERVICE_DEMAND=$(echo "$VISITS * $SERVICE_DEMAND" | bc)`

Comment: quote your variables and you should be fine. `echo "$WR+$RD" | bc`

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `bc`, consider switching to a better programming language. Bash is simply unsuited for mathematics.

Answer (score 2):

Use `bc` to do [float calculations in Bash](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/floating-point-math-bash).

Answer (score 2):

To set the precision (number of digits of the answer to the right of the decimal point),
write:

```
WR=5
RD=7
VISITS=$[WR+RD]
SERVICE_DEMAND=.0895406
SERVICE_DEMAND=`echo "scale=5; $VISITS * $SERVICE_DEMAND" |bc -l`
echo Service Demand = $SERVICE_DEMAND
```

This outputs:

```
Service Demand = 1.0744872
```

The **scale=5**  sets 5 digits of precision; the backquotes cause the contained expression to be
evaluated and the ouput (from the **bc -l**) to be assigned to your variable.

Comment: Thanks

But...

It returned the following mistake:

(standard_in) 2: syntax error

Comment: I just ran this again on GNU bash, version 4.0.35(1)-release (i586-suse-linux-gnu)

Comment: Alucard, Perhaps your cut-and-pasting introduced a \r\n.  Try <code>dos2unix scriptname</code>  on your copy.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use an external program like `bc` to do floating-point math in your scripts.

Something like:

`echo ($WR+$RD)*$SERVICE_DEMAND | bc`